# Space between item label and paragraph, enumitem

Tags: enumitem

In the MWE below, how can I reduce the space between the (i)/(ii) and their respective paragraphs, i.e. the blue lines? I would like to

1. keep the "exercises" labels hugging the left margin
2. keep the "subparts" labels hugging the left margin

If I use the `labelsep` parameter, the (i) and (ii) are dragged away from the left margin. Moreover, I don't think I'm using the `widest` parameter correctly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin={1.25in,1.1in}]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools,enumitem,lipsum}

\newlist{exercises}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[exercises]{label=\textbf{\thesection-\arabic*.\;},align=right,leftmargin=0pt,itemsep=15pt}
\newlist{subparts}{enumerate}{2}
\setlist[subparts]{label=(\roman*),align=left,widest=i}

\begin{document}

\section{Testing section}

\begin{exercises}
%
\item \lipsum[1]
\item
\begin{subparts}
\item \lipsum[2]
\item \lipsum[3]
\end{subparts}
\item
\end{exercises}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you want the first level list labels in the margin?

Comment: Yes, the idea is that they are labeling exercises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `widest`-parameter, from page 5 in the [docs](http://ctan.uib.no/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/enumitem.pdf), says it should be used in conjunction with the `*`-values. That is if we do `leftmargin=*` then the `widest=i` would decide how much leftmargin there should be. This used in combination with `labelsep` gives you a result that I think is what you want:

```
\setlist[subparts]{label=(\roman*),align=left,widest=ii,
    labelsep=0pt,leftmargin=*}
```

Where labelsep is the distance from the counter mark. If you increase the `widest` you increase the space between the "anchor point" of the label (try changing it to e.g. `widest=i` or `widest=iii` or `widest=asdf`). `labelsep` increases extra distance from the widest label and out.

Doing this produces:

[image]

Here is the code in it's entirety:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin={1.25in,1.1in}]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools,enumitem,lipsum}

\newlist{exercises}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[exercises]{label=\textbf{\thesection-\arabic*.\;},align=right,leftmargin=0pt,itemsep=15pt}
\newlist{subparts}{enumerate}{2}
\setlist[subparts]{label=(\roman*),align=left,widest=i,
    labelsep=0pt,leftmargin=*}

\begin{document}

    \section{Testing section}

     \begin{exercises}
         %
         \item \lipsum[1]
         \item
         \begin{subparts}
             \item \lipsum[2]
             \item \lipsum[3]
         \end{subparts}
         \item
     \end{exercises}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin={1.25in,1.1in}, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools,enumitem,lipsum}

\newlist{exercises}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[exercises]{label=\textbf{\thesection-\arabic*.\;}, labelsep=2pt, leftmargin=0pt, itemsep=15pt}
\newlist{subparts}{enumerate}{2}
\setlist[subparts]{label=(\roman*), wide=0pt, leftmargin=* , labelsep=-3pt}

\begin{document}

\section{Testing section}

\begin{exercises}
%
\item \lipsum[1]
\item
\begin{subparts}
\item \lipsum[2]
\item \lipsum[3]
\end{subparts}
\item
\end{exercises}

\end{document}
```

[image]